# How to get balance through tezos-client

Tags: tezos-client

I have installed the `tezos-client` but don't know how to check the balance for an address. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the balance for an address by running `tezos-client get balance for <address>`. Remember to be connected to a node first. You can do that by following this tutorial: https://assets.tqtezos.com/docs/setup/1-tezos-client/

If the balance is zero or unexpected, your connected node might be out of sync. You can check that by running `tezos-client get timestamp`.